# How do I return pointer to an array of function pointers?

Tags: arrays, function, pointers

I have an array of function pointers

```
typedef uint32_t   (*test)     ( void );

static const test tests[] =
{
 test_1  ,
 test_2  ,
 test_3  ,
 test_4  ,
 test_5  ,
  
};
```

I want to return a pointer to the above function pointer array . Can anyone pls help me do it.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should be able to write `const test *get_tests(void);`. Here we remember that the type of the array is convertible to the type of a pointer to the first element and do it the easy way.

Good use of `typedef` for the function pointer to make your life easier.